Как производятся платежи по привязанной карте?
Вот привязал я карту к какому-то приложению, на первый раз подтвердил это всё кодом из пуша от банка, например. А каким образом приложение в последующем использует платежные данные для оплаты без моего подтверждения? Может есть какая-то общая банковская система для этого?

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не о программировании.

@Эникейщик можно попробовать свести к программированию такого механизма привязки карт)

После первой оплаты картой, банк выдает продавцу токен для дальнейшей работы с картой без дополнительных проверок. Такой токен используется в оплате подписок, чтобы не вводить данные заново каждый месяц

Это работает на основе рекурентных платежей.
Клиент совершает первый платеж, на основании которого создается токен. В дальнейшем он будет использоваться для таких.
Данные карты магазину не передаются, а только токен. Клиент может отключить автоплатеж в любой момент.
